# Mvc section not rendered in head but in body

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I encountered a strange behavior for @RenderSection in the head section of _Layout.

```
@section AddToHead{ 
    <meta name="test" />
    <open-graph og-title="@Model.Test.OG.Title" og-image="@Model.Test.OG.Image" og-url="@Model.Test.OG.Url" og-type="@Model.Test.OG.Type"></open-graph>
}
```

1. meta => is plain html
2. open-graph => is a taghelper which returns html

and added on _Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    @await RenderSectionAsync("AddToHead", required: false)
</head>
```

I tried already with RenderSectionAsync and RenderSection. No difference.

When I check the result on page it is as follows (total different result)

**View Source Code**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta name="test" />
    <div><meta property='og:title' content='TestTitle' /><meta property='og:type' content='Article' /><meta property='og:url' content='TestURL' /><meta property='og:image' content='TestBild' /></div>
</head>
```

**Developer Tools**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <meta name="test" />

</head>
<body>
  <div><meta property='og:title' content='TestTitle' /><meta property='og:type' content='Article' /><meta property='og:url' content='TestURL' /><meta property='og:image' content='TestBild' /></div>
</body>
```

Facebook sees my site like Developer Tools does.

What I'm doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer tools shows how the browser interprets your HTML which is why you're seeing a difference between viewing source and the developer tools.

As for why that's happening, `<div>` tags in the `<head>` are problematic. Most browsers these days will interpret those `<div>` tags as if they were in the body. If you were to render your `<meta />` tags without the surrounding div all should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Taylor. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, that included not only `@RenderSection`, but also `<meta>` tags and all other `<head>` content.

The solution was to move all usings from layout to a separate file `_ViewImports.cshtml` as stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-8.0#importing-shared-directives).